How to prevent page reload after API request in React?
Could someone help me prevent the page from reloading after an API request? Do you know how to manage this behavior correctly?
https://github.com/desioncezar/react-how-prevent-page-reload
To run the project:
Terminal 1 npm install
Terminal 1 npm run json
Terminal 2 npm start
I created 3 different react implementations (Hook component, Class component, query component) to add a new option in a dropdown component without reloading the page.
Thank you for helping me. I delegated to the parent page to request the API and sent the results to the child with props, and the page is still refreshing. If I manually change the JSON file the page reloads. I updated the GitHub repository with the new implementation. Should I give up and move to Next.js?
Parent
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// Components
import Header from '../components/Header';
//import HookDropdownDecision from '../components/HookDropdownDecision';
//import ClassDropdownDecision from '../components/ClassDropdownDecision';
//import QueryDropdownDecision from '../components/QueryDropdownDecision';
//import HookFormDropdownDecision from '../components/HookFormDropdownDecision';
import PropsDropdownDecision from '../components/PropsDropdownDecision';

const Home = () => {

    const [decisions, setDecisions] = useState([]);

    const getDecision = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/decision');
        return response.json();
    };

    const postDecision = async (data) => {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/decision', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        return response.json();
    };  

    useEffect(() => {
        getDecision().then((data) => {
            setDecisions(data);
        });
    }, []);

    function joinNewDecision(decision) {

        postDecision({ id: decision.id, name: decision.name }).then((data) => {
            setDecisions([...decisions, { data }]);
        });

        console.log(decision);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Header />

            {/* <HookDropdownDecision /> */}

            {/* <ClassDropdownDecision /> */}

            {/* <QueryDropdownDecision /> */}

            {/* <HookFormDropdownDecision /> */}

            <PropsDropdownDecision
                dataDecision={decisions}
                joinNewDecision={joinNewDecision}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default React.memo(Home);


Child
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { MultiSelect } from 'primereact/multiselect';
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';
import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";

const PropsDropdownDecision = (props) => {

    //const [decisions, setDecisions] = useState(props.dataDecision);
    const [selectedDecision, setSelectedDecision] = useState('');
    const [newDecision, setNewDecision] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {

    }, []);

    const addDecision = () => {

        if (newDecision.trim() && !props.dataDecision.find(item => item.name === newDecision.trim())) {
            let newId = props.dataDecision.length + 1;

            // Memory            
            //setDecisions([...decisions, { id: newId, name: newDecision }]);
            props.joinNewDecision({ id: newId, name: newDecision });

            // API
            //postDecision({ id: newId, name: newDecision }).then((data) => {
            //    setDecisions([...decisions, { data }]);
            //});

            setNewDecision('');
            console.log(props.dataDecision);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>

            <div className="px-4 py-8 md:px-6 lg:px-8 flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div className="surface-card border-round shadow-2 p-4">
                    <div className="text-900 font-medium mb-2 text-xl">Hook Decisions</div>
                    <p className="mt-0 mb-4 p-0 line-height-3">Add or choose one or more decisions.</p>
                    <div className="flex mb-4 flex-column lg:flex-row">

                        <div className="surface-50 p-6 flex-auto">
                            <div className="text-600 mb-3">New Decision</div>
                            <InputText type="text"
                                value={newDecision}
                                onChange={(e) => setNewDecision(e.target.value)}
                                className="border-noround"
                                style={{ minWidth: "250px", height: "40px" }}
                                placeholder="Add" />
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                icon="pi pi-check"
                                label="Confirm"
                                className="border-noround"
                                style={{ height: "40px" }}
                                onClick={(e) => addDecision(e)}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="surface-50 p-6 flex-auto">
                            <div className="text-600 mb-3">Select Decision</div>
                            <MultiSelect
                                value={selectedDecision}
                                onChange={(e) => setSelectedDecision(e.value)}
                                options={props.dataDecision}
                                optionLabel="name"
                                placeholder="Choose"
                                maxSelectedLabels={0}
                                className="border-noround"
                                style={{ minWidth: "250px", height: "40px" }}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </>
    );
};

export default React.memo(PropsDropdownDecision);



Not unless you describe the problem, and include the [mcve] code in your post. Talk about what you set out to do, show the code you wrote to do that, talk about the problem that code has and what debugging and (re)searching you already did. Even if the rest of the internet goes down, your question should still have all the details necessary to answer it.

I found the problem, the JSON file is in the app's public folder where the Api persists the changes and React refreshes the app after seeing the file has changed. I must find a solution to control this behavior or move the JSON file to another folder. I noticed that in a Next.JS project, it doesn't happen.

Great: please [edit] your post and rewrite it to include those details (not as an "edit" section, just update your post so that it read like a single coherent post. You're not just asking for yourself, you're also asking for every future visitor), as well as following the posting guidelines as already requested in the above comment.
